# Angular 10: Autenticación usando interceptors,

Tags: javascript, angular

Estoy tratando de que el token me aparezca en el navegador en network, pero me aparece null(Authorization: Bearer null). Este es mi codigo:

```
export class TokenInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private auth: AuthService) {}

  intercept(req, next) {
    console.log(this.auth.obtenerToken());
    const tokenReq = req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer' + this.auth.obtenerToken(),
      },
    });
    return next.handle(tokenReq);
  }
}
```

En consola me aparece el token, pero en network del navegador no.

En auth.service.ts tengo la funcion obtenerToken() asi:

```
  obtenerToken(){
    return localStorage.getItem('token');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

te paso mi implementación

```
tokenReq = req.clone({
headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + (tuformadeobtenereltoken)
});
```

Una recomendación en auth.service.ts
Declara `token: String;`
en tu contructor `this.token = localStorage.getItem('token');`

Crea un metogo get `get token(){return token}` un método set `set token(value){this.token = value; localstorage.setItem('token', this.token)}` la idea es que manejes todo el token desde el serivicio, tu código queda mas limpio.

Ahora en el interceptor tu token quedaría así:

```
tokenReq = req.clone({
headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.auth.token)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedo compartirte una sugerencia para que realices la implantación de esta manera.

```
intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return from(this.handleAccess(req, next));
  }

  private async handleAccess(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Promise<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    let customHeaders;
    if (token) {
      customHeaders = req.clone({
        headers: req.headers
          .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
          .append('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
      });
    } else {
      customHeaders = req.clone({
        headers: req.headers
          .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      });
    }
    return next.handle(customHeaders);
  }
```